# ParseException: Unparseable date Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

[this is my code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7YFX.png)

I have tried every solution that is given on StackOverflow kindly please tell me the solution to my problem

Kotlin Code:

```
fun getMessageDateFromString(date: String): String {
        var date1: Date? = null

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH)
        try {
            simpleDateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(date)
            simpleDateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            Log.e("Error here${date}", e.toString())
        }
```

And this is the Error in exception:

```
/propAdapter: 10
E/Error here2021-03-15T17:07:34.304019+05:00: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-03-15T17:07:34.304019+05:00" (at offset 26)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the stack trace here? its easier to read here then on the picture (additionally someone can copy and paste the code in their own ide to try it your)

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to achieve. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: sure i will add the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you are passing wrong datetime format. You should be used this DateTime format:

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"

Please try above datetime format. It will help to solve your date parsing issue.

Here, you have added ' ' sign on Z character. Please remove it.

Comment: thanks alot it solved my problem ... jayesh Kanani if you please explain what was the issue with format . it will be very helpful

Comment: Here,Millisecond value is large in DateTime. And, you had passed incorrect Millisecond format(SSS). So, I changed this format with SSSSSS and removed  '  ' sign from Z character.
After that, issue is solved.